# New search bar flickers

Tags: bug, search

The new search bar in the top has a bug.

After you enter your search text and press search (or enter) the magnifier icon overlaps the search text and flickers two times.

Browser/OS:
Firefox 51/Windows 7

Does NOT appear with
Chrome/Internet Explorer 11/Windows 7

[image: search icon flickers]

Comment: updated: Error appears in Firefox.

Comment: This question is Stack Overflow specific, so please ask it on Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: No repro on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 51.1.0